# How to build this function

Tags: html

I'm trying to figure out how to build a HTML module on the website builder Enjin. I have extremely limited experience with HTML, so I took some code from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link) but it doesn't quite do what I want. Ideally the module would look something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/5w1vgTN.png). There is an events calendar that the module would be linked with so that the sign up button would reflect changes on the calendar. [Here is the website](http://69thid.com/home).  Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

Press 'Run code snippet' button below to see the output.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Events Sign-Up</title>
  <style>
    .eventtable,
    .eventtable td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      font-family: Calibri;
    }
    td {
      padding: 1em;
      border: solid 5px white;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
    .col1 {
      background-color: #CBCBCB;
    }
    .eventname {
      color: #484848;
    }
    .eventdaytime {
      color: #830D0D;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .col2 {
      background-color: #92FF7F;
    }
    .eventstatus {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      color: #404040;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="eventtable">
    <tbody>
      <!-- ROW 1 ------------>
      <tr>
        <td class="col1">
          <div class="eventname">
            69th Infantry Division Private Ops Night
          </div>
          <div class="eventdaytime">
            Sunday 7:45 PM
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
          <div class="eventstatus">
            Sign Up
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <!-- ROW 2 ------------>
      <tr>
        <td class="col1">
          <div class="eventname">
            69th Infantry Division Private Ops Night
          </div>
          <div class="eventdaytime">
            Sunday 7:45 PM
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
          <div class="eventstatus">
            Sign Up
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I can get the rest of it from here. I appreciate the help!